# Change return symbol of keyboard in android

Tags: android, keyboard

How can I change the `return symbol` on the default Android keyboard?

Comment: Do you mean the layout of the soft keyboard for input? I don't think you can change the design of built-in keyboard, but the keyboard is just an app and could be replaced by another one that fits your needs more ([look here for example](http://www.simplemobilereview.com/change-your-android-soft-keyboard-system/)).

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by..

youredittext is the edittext...

```
youredittext.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);
youredittext.setImeActionLabel......with this you can specify a string 


youredittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
        performSearch();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can't you would have to implement a custom keyboard.

Or you could but ONLY on a rooted phone.